# Fabric proguard rules

Tags: android, proguard

I have found on fabric page following note

> For Fabric to properly de-obfuscate your crash reports, you need to
>   remove this line from your ProGuard config:
>
> -printmapping mapping.txt

Can anyone clear for me this thing. How I will reobfuscate crash logs by myself if I remove this line?

Answer (score 1):

As the documentation for [shrinking Android code](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/shrink-code.html) states, the file:

```
mapping.txt
```

*Provides a translation between the original and obfuscated class, method, and field names.*

Fabric resolves the real names of classe and methods the were passed through Proguard. To do this, it needs the mapping, which is written by Proguard in this file.

Comment: I know what does this file mean, and how Fabric resolve real names and so forth, but why I need to remove mapping file name from proguard?